# how to change default 'pk' to 'id' or others in django-rest-framework?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

like this:
the default field in django-rest-framework'route is `pk`

```
@detail_route(methods=['GET'])
    def run(self, reuqest, pk):
       print pk
       return xxx
```

this url's base_url is `sched`
then I get `0.0.0.0:8000/sched/12/run/`
I can get `pk=12` in method `run`

now I want change `pk` to `id`
make me can do like this:

```
@detail_route(methods=['GET'])
    def run(self, reuqest, id):
       print id
       return xxx
```

how can i change it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set `lookup_field` in class, that can fixed this question